# IF - ELSE statement Google Sheets various values

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If a cell was "x","y", or "z", I would like to spit out XYZ

Else "a", "b", or "c", then ABC

ELSE

assign "MNO"

I am currently working with this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("x",A2)), IF(ISERROR(FIND("a",A2)), "ABC", "MNO"),"XYZ")
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 why add the regex tag?  The OP did not say one thing about that in the question.  I know your answer uses it but you made it seem like that was the only answer the op wants.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "x|y|z"), "XYZ", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "a|b|c"), "ABC", "MNO"))
```

[image: 0]

---

if A2 is number use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2&"", "1|2|3"), "XYZ", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2&"", "a|b|c"), "ABC", "MNO"))
```

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "x|y|z"), "XYZ", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "a|b|c"), "ABC", "MNO"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OR:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(A2={"x","y","z"}),"XYZ",IF(OR(A2={"a","b","c"}),"ABC","MNO")))
```

[image]